# some words display as '?'' when using french language in MS Teams app localization(manifest 1.5)

Tags: localization, microsoft-teams

- **Description:** Teams display wrong values in app static tab and 'what can i do' input command
              For example,value 'élément' display '�l�ment',it seems that Teams can not recognize the char 'é'
- **Manifest Version:** 1.5
- **Language:** fr-fr

Manifest.json

```
{
   //hide bot other message
   "localizationInfo": {
                "defaultLanguageTag": "en",
                "additionalLanguages": [            
                    {
                        "languageTag": "fr-fr",
                        "file": "fr-fr.json"
                    }
                ]
   }
}
```

fr-fr.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/fr-fr/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.Localization.schema.json",
  "name.short": "Test",
  "name.full": "TestFullName",
  "description.short": "short description example",
  "description.full": "full description example",
  "staticTabs[0].name": "Nouveautés",
  "bots[0].commandLists[0].commands[0].title": "Restaurer élément",
  "bots[0].commandLists[0].commands[0].description": "Restaurer élément for test",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lin's Master, for all the French regions, you need to set your "languageTag" = "fr". Please follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-localization).

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been solved when I check the installer bot package.It seems that the App Studio can not recognize some words like 'é'. So close this issue!